# When I am creating React App in Ubuntu 20.04, Why does it show some warnings in my terminal? It shows some module incompatibilities

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npx

Creating React App in Ubuntu 20.04, in my terminal:

> [1/4] Resolving packages...
>
> [2/4] Fetching packages...
>
> info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this
> module.
>
> info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed
> compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
>
> info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this
> module.
>
> info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed
> compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. [3/4] Linking
> dependencies...

*Warnings in terminal:*

> warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin >
> tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >=
> 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
>
> warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer
> dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".

Answer (score 2):

It is an optional dependency and is only needed in MacOS environments. Linux and Windows both provide native ways to do what this dependency is needed for on MacOS. *Just ignore it.*